# hamilton path & topological sort

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that a Hamilton path is the only topological sort.
I think I need to show that in case there are two topological sorts,
none of them is a Hamilton path.

How can I prove that a Hamilton path is the only topological sort
in a DAG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you need to observe is that an Hamilton path is a path that goes through all vertices. Think how can one dag have 2 different topological sorts